# Elixir - Deadlock between library dependencies

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

### The context

I'm building my own library of code for dealing with ElasticSearch, using the Tirexs package. This is my first time heading deep into macros, dependencies, use, import and several other of the most advanced features Elixir offers.

For that I have define a `Document` struct which looks roughly like this, (`/lib/data/document.ex`)

```
defmodule Document do
  use Document.ORM
  import Document.Builder, only: [build_document: 2]
  import Document.Builder.Validations, only: [is_document_valid?: 1, collect_errors: 1]

  defstruct [valid?: false, errors: nil, fields: %{}]

  def something do
    # uses imported functions from Document.Builder and Documen.Builder.Validations
  end
end
```

The `Document` module then uses several other functions from the `Document.ORM` module which don't seem to be the cause of the error.

### The problem

My error is the following

```
Compilation failed because of a deadlock between files.
dataobj_1          | The following files depended on the following modules:
dataobj_1          | 
dataobj_1          |   web/controllers/document_controller.ex => Document
dataobj_1          |             lib/data/document/builder.ex => Document.Builder.AuxiliarBuilder
dataobj_1          |                     lib/data/document.ex => Document.Builder
dataobj_1          |      lib/data/document/orm/bulk/utils.ex => Document
dataobj_1          |    lib/data/document/builder/auxiliar.ex => Document
```

There's a deadlock which I don't know how to approach, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

The first dependency, the `document_controller` one occurs (*I think*) because it both refer to the module `Document` and the `%Document` struct in different places:

```
defmodule Data.DocumentController do
  use Data.Web, :controller

  def create(conn, %{"document" => document_params}) do
      {:ok, doc} = document_params 
        |> Document.new
      case Document.save(doc) do
        {:ok, record} ->
          conn
          |> put_status(201)
          |> render(Data.DocumentView, "document.json", payload: Document.find(record._id))
        {:error, map_of_errors} ->
          conn
          |> put_status(422)
          |> render(Data.ErrorView, "422.json", errors: map_of_errors)
      end
  end
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "document" => document}) do
    case Document.update(id, document) do
      %Document{valid?: false, errors: errors} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(422)
        |> render(Data.ErrorView, "422.json", errors: errors)
      docset ->
        conn
        |> put_status(200)
        |> render(Data.DocumentView, "update.json", payload: docset)
    end
  end
```

The other dependencies also refer to both the module and the struct, so I'm thinking the deadlock has to do with this. But I'm lost about what to do.

If there's necessary I can share more code, but to start the question I think it is enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to remove an `import` statement in one of the two module files to resolve this. Elixir *does* allow some 'circular dependencies', e.g. functions in either module can call functions in the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have circular dependencies.

```
Document -> Document.Builder -> Document.AuxiliarBuilder -> Document
```

Generally speaking, you should avoid child modules (`Document.Builder`, `Document.AuxiliarBuilder`) from calling their parent (`Document`). It sounds like you need to extract those functions out of `Document` and put them elsewhere.

**Note**: Elixir does not actually have a concept of parent and child modules. I am just using the words here because that is how I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the circular dependency was happening because of the definition of the struct, namely `%Document`, and confusion with the module name.

Moving the struct definition into its own separate file (first couple of lines [here](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/modules/#structs) were the hint), and changing the module name from `Document` to `Data.Document` (`%Data.Document`) was enough to solve all circular dependencies.